# Command program, mostly working, bugs here and there

Tags: java, loops, command

I'm writing a program to take in commands from the user, and output accordingly. The program keeps asking for input, until the user inputs "Quit" as a command.

Commands are:

Factorial # (takes one number as an argument)

**Outputs the factorial of the number, Ex.**

```
Factorial 5
5! == 120
```

GCD # # (Takes 2 numbers as arguments)

**outputs the greatest common divisor between 2 numbers (Recursively.) Ex.**

```
gcd 5 10
gcd(5, 10) == 5
```

Sorted # #... (Takes as many numbers as the user wants)
**checks to see if the numbers after the command are in order. Ex.**

```
sorted 1 2 3 4 5
That list is sorted.
sorted 1 2 3 5 4
Out of order: 4 after 5.
```

Now all this works pretty good. nothing wrong as of now, what im struggling with, when the user enters a letter instead of a number, it should try and catch an **InputMismatchException**, this kind of works. for example.

if the user enters a letter it would say this.

```
Factorial j
Not a number: For input string: j
```

**BUT**

```
Factorial 5 j
5! == 120
```

it would go on how it normally would, but it takes the "j" as the next command, for so if i type Factorial 5 quit, it would print the factorial then quit, i don't know why this is happening.

another thing is i want to throw and catch an exception if the arguments are too much for the command, so the user cant type Factorial 5 10, and it would just calculate the factorial of 5, it would print an error message, i dont know how to achieve this.

Heres my code as of now.
A09.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @author Amr Ghoneim (A00425709)
 *
 */
public class A09 {

static int counter = 0;

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String command;
    String[] commands = { "sorted", "factorial", "gcd", "help", "quit" };
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    intro();
    help();
    System.out.println("Please type in your command below.");
    boolean isValid = true;

    while (isValid) {
        System.out.print(">>> ");
        command = scnr.next().toLowerCase();
        // FACTORIAL
        if (commands[1].startsWith(command)
                && commands[1].contains(command)) {
            try {
                int num = scnr.nextInt();
                if (num >= 0) {
                    System.out.println(num + "! == " + factorial(num));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + num + "! undefined");
                }

            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Not a number: For input string: " + scnr.next());
            }

            // GCD
        } else if (commands[2].startsWith(command)
                && commands[2].contains(command)) {
            try {
                int numA, numB;
                numA = scnr.nextInt();
                numB = scnr.nextInt();
                System.out.println("gcd(" + numA + ", " + numB + ") == "
                        + GCD(numA, numB));
            } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Not a number: For input string: " + scnr.next());

            }
            // SORTED
        } else if (commands[0].startsWith(command)
                && commands[0].contains(command)) {
            try {
                List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(scnr.nextLine(),
                        " ");
                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    nums.add(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
                }
                sorted(nums);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println("Not a number: For input string: ");
            }
            // QUIT
        } else if (commands[4].startsWith(command)
                && commands[4].contains(command)) {
            isValid = false;
            quit();
            // HELP
        } else if (commands[3].startsWith(command)
                && commands[3].contains(command)) {
            help();
        }
    }
}

public static void intro() {
    System.out.println("This program can calculate factorials, "
            + "\nGCD, and check to see if a list of numbers are in order"
            + "\n-----------------------------------"
            + "\nMade by Amr Ghoneim (A00425709)"
            + "\n-----------------------------------");
}

public static int factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;

    } else {
        int num = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            num *= i;
        }
        return num;
    }
}

public static int GCD(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return GCD(b, a % b);
    }
}

public static void help() {
    System.out.println("Valid commands are:" + "\n - factorial #"
            + "\n     The product of all numbers from 1 to #."
            + "\n     (The argument must not be negative.)" + "\n - gcd # #"
            + "\n     The greatest common divisor of the two numbers."
            + "\n     The biggest number that divides evenly into both of 
them."
            + "\n - sorted #..."
            + "\n     Whether the numbers are in order from smallest to 
largest."
            + "\n     If not, then where the first out-of-order number is."
            + "\n - help" + "\n     This help message." + "\n - quit"
            + "\n     End the program.");
}

public static boolean sorted(List<Integer> nums) {
    for (int i = 1; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        if (nums.get(i - 1) > nums.get(i)) {
            System.out.println("Out of order: " + nums.get(i) + " after "
                    + nums.get(i - 1));
            return false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("That list is sorted.");
    return true;
}

public static void quit() {
    System.out.println("Good-bye.");
    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

What im missing is finding out how many arguments the user is putting, if too much print a message, and for the sorted command, i cant get it to print the letter the user puts. and for some reason when i input "Factorial 5 5" is would print the ">>>" twice instead of once. theres just some bugs here and there, can someone guide me on how i would approach this stuff, or show some examples?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: I have been trying to learn how to use it, for some reason i can't seem to get it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code so that it will work as what you have described. Just look at the code comments for details. Feel free to comment for clarifications.

Modified code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String command;
        String[] commands = { "sorted", "factorial", "gcd", "help", "quit" };
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        intro();
        help();
        System.out.println("Please type in your command below.");
        boolean isValid = true;

        while (isValid) {
            System.out.print(">>> ");
            command = scnr.nextLine().toLowerCase(); // instead of getting the input per space, get all the input per
                                                        // line
            String[] userCommand = command.split(" "); // split the line by spaces

            // check if the command has at least 2 parameters except for "help" and "quit"
            if (!commands[3].equals(userCommand[0]) && !commands[4].equals(userCommand[0]) && userCommand.length < 2) {
                System.out.println("Invalid command: " + command);
                continue;
            }

            // since you know that the first word will be the command, you just have to get
            // the value of index 0
            // FACTORIAL
            // use equals do not use startsWith or contains since it will hold true for
            // inputs "FACTORIALINVALID 4"
            if (commands[1].equals(userCommand[0])) {
                // check if the command has the correct number of parameters, in this case it
                // must have exactly 2 parameters
                if (userCommand.length != 2) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid command: " + command);
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    // get the number for the factorial and convert it into an int
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(userCommand[1]);
                    if (num >= 0) {
                        System.out.println(num + "! == " + factorial(num));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Error: " + num + "! undefined");
                    }

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Not a number: For input string: " + command);
                }

                // GCD
                // use equals do not use startsWith or contains since it will hold true for
                // inputs "GCDINVALID 4 5"
            } else if (commands[2].equals(userCommand[0])) {
                // check if the command has the correct number of parameters, in this case it
                // must have exactly 3 parameters
                if (userCommand.length != 3) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid command: " + command);
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    // get the number for the GCD and convert it into an int
                    int numA, numB;
                    numA = Integer.parseInt(userCommand[1]);
                    numB = Integer.parseInt(userCommand[2]);
                    System.out.println("gcd(" + numA + ", " + numB + ") == " + GCD(numA, numB));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Not a number: For input string: " + command);

                }
                // SORTED

                // use equals do not use startsWith or contains since it will hold true for
                // inputs "SORTEDINVALID 4 5 6"
            } else if (commands[0].equals(userCommand[0])) {
                // check if the command has the correct number of parameters, in this case it
                // must at least 2 parameters
                if (userCommand.length < 2) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid command: " + command);
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                    // get the list
                    for (int i = 1; i < userCommand.length; i++) {
                        nums.add(Integer.parseInt(userCommand[i]));
                    }
                    sorted(nums);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Not a number: For input string: " + command);
                }
                // QUIT
                // use equals do not use startsWith or contains since it will hold true for
                // inputs "QUITINVALID"
            } else if (commands[4].equals(userCommand[0])) {
                isValid = false;
                quit();
                // HELP
                // use equals do not use startsWith or contains since it will hold true for
                // inputs "HELPINVALID"
            } else if (commands[3].equals(userCommand[0])) {
                help();
            }
        }
        scnr.close();
    }

    public static void intro() {
        System.out.println("This program can calculate factorials, "
                + "\nGCD, and check to see if a list of numbers are in order" + "\n-----------------------------------"
                + "\nMade by Amr Ghoneim (A00425709)" + "\n-----------------------------------");
    }

    public static int factorial(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;

        } else {
            int num = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                num *= i;
            }
            return num;
        }
    }

    public static int GCD(int a, int b) {
        if (b == 0) {
            return a;
        } else {
            return GCD(b, a % b);
        }
    }

    public static void help() {
        System.out.println("Valid commands are:" + "\n - factorial #" + "\n     The product of all numbers from 1 to #."
                + "\n     (The argument must not be negative.)" + "\n - gcd # #"
                + "\n     The greatest common divisor of the two numbers."
                + "\n     The biggest number that divides evenly into both of them." + "\n - sorted #..."
                + "\n     Whether the numbers are in order from smallest to largest."
                + "\n     If not, then where the first out-of-order number is." + "\n - help"
                + "\n     This help message." + "\n - quit" + "\n     End the program.");
    }

    public static boolean sorted(List<Integer> nums) {
        for (int i = 1; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            if (nums.get(i - 1) > nums.get(i)) {
                System.out.println("Out of order: " + nums.get(i) + " after " + nums.get(i - 1));
                return false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("That list is sorted.");
        return true;
    }

    public static void quit() {
        System.out.println("Good-bye.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code looks good, i did some testing and if i was to type "Factorial 5 j j" just to test the exceptions. it outputs "Not a number: For input string: j
5! == 120" it ignores the first j, takes the second j as the input string, and then it goes through with the function and solve it anyway, its not supposed to do that, any ideas why?

Comment: I tried to input "Factorial 5 j j" but my result is "Invalid command: factorial 5 j j" thus I think you have miscopied my code.

Comment: oh you're right i ran my other program somehow, thanks!

Comment: @Amr If I solved your question please mark my solution as the correct answer. Thanks